# parse strings separated by 2 elements

Tags: objective-c, string

On Mac OS X, in Ojective-C, I wanted to know if anyone could give me some pointers as to how I could parse strings contained between "x" and "y".

My current code only enables me to separate the strings separated by one componennt :

```
NSArray * allLines = [theDataObject componentsSeparatedByString:@"word-1"];
```

Ideally, I would like to isolate the strings contained between @"word-1" and @"word-2".

Could anyone help please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when there is no `word-2` in between two `word-1`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation for `NSScanner`.  The methods you want are `-scanUpToString:intoString:` and `-scanString:intoString:`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str = [theDataObject stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"word-2" withString:@"word-1"];
NSArray *allLines = [str componetnsSeperatedByString:@"word-1"];
```

You don't care whether its word-1 or word-2 as those do not come back in the array anyways.

Comment: Actually, when I NSLog allLines I don't get ONLY what's contained between word-1 and word-2 ...

Comment: No indeed they don't appear. But what I'm trying to do is isolate only what is between word-1 and word-2, the problem is that I also see what is between word-2 and word-1. Not sure I'm making myself clear so let me explain quickly: I have a text file containing **word-1 "blah blah blah" \n word-2 "yah yah yah"**. With this method I get **"blah blah blah" "yah yah yah"** I would like to only see **"blah blah blah"** and leave out **"yah yah yah"**. Does that make sense?

Comment: @WeeBey You can use NSScanner ( NSString wrapper ) or NSString rangeOfString to divide the string into parts yourself.